# Filtering elements from a list based on conditions in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list of routes

```
path(chicago,milwaukee).
path(milwaukee,detroit).
path(chicago,detroit).
path(detroit, newyork).
path(newyork, boston).
path(atlanta,boston).
```

I have a predicate routefrom which gives all the cities between start & end. 
For example:

```
?- routefrom(chicago,newyork,X).
X=[chicago,milwaukee,detroit,newyork]
```

To get all the routes I have

```
allroutes(Start,End,P) :- findall(X,pathfrom(Start,End,X),P).
```

Example:

```
?- allroutes(chicago,neywork,P).
X=[[chicago,milwaukee,detroit,newyork],[chicago,detroit,newyork]].
```

I have a predicate rule `goodroute(M)` which returns true if the routes does not contain milwaukee and contains either chicago or newyork.
Example:

```
?- goodroute([chicago, milwaukee,detroit]).
false

?-goodroute([chicago,detroit,newyork,boston]).
true
```

Now,
I need to filter out the routes which have milwaukee and get a list which has chicago or newyork from the result of allroutes.
I tried

```
filerroute :- exclude(maplist(goodroute(findall(X,pathfrom(Start,End,X),P).
```

What I am trying to do is map the goodroute on the result of findall so that some of it would be true & some would be false and exclude would eliminate the false.
I am not exactly sure how exclude works.
How do I filter out the elements which are false according to the goodroute predicate and get a list of elements having only elements matching the true condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exclude` and `include` (which you really want) take a predicate name as their first argument:

```
goodroutes(From, To, Routes) :-
    allroutes(From, To, All),
    include(goodroute, All, Routes).
```

Though it would be more efficient to filter out the bad routes during the call to `findall`, since then you wouldn't have to build the set of all routes first:

```
goodroutes(From, To, Routes) :-
    findall(Route, (pathfrom(From, To, Route), goodroute(Route)), Routes).
```

Note the `( , )`; we're giving `findall` a conjunction of two goals as its second argument.

Comment: Thanks. The one using findall looks more efficient than the one with include.

And in `findall(Route, (pathfrom(From, To, Route), goodroute(Route)), Routes).` , we can use as many goals for it to match right? If I have more condition I need to meet, I just do `findall(Route, (pathfrom(From, To, Route), goodroute(Route),another_condition), Routes).` right?

Comment: @RBK: that's right, and it's also more portable. `include` is nice if you get a fully constructed list as input, but filtering early can save a *lot* of time in the end.